# Java compare lists having different types of objects

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I have two lists containing different types of objects. The lists can:

1. Be Null.
2. Not Null, but may not have any element.
3. Can have exactly one element.
4. Can have more than one element.

I need to do some operation only if there is only one element in either of the list, and not both. A sample code will be some thing like this:

```
public void function1(List<int> list1, List<String> list2)
{
  if(list1 != null && list2 != null && list1.length + list2.length == 1)
  {
    if(list1.length > 0)
    {
        doSomethingWithIntList(list1)
    }
    else
    {
        doSomethingWithStringList(list2)
    }
  }
  else if(list1 != null && list1.length == 1)
  {
    doSomethingWithIntList(list1)
  }
  else if (list2 != null && list2.length == 1)
  {
    doSomethingWithStringList(list2)
  }
}
```

Is there some better and elegant way of doing the above using Java 8 features? Some way by which I can avoid these many `if-else`. Or are there any Apache libraries which may be used in the above? Thanks!

Comment: `List<int>` will not compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I suggest that instead of coding a bunch of `if-else` statements that are long and difficult to parse, break the logic into smaller methods. (Noted also by Flown).

Also, all of the null checks are hard to read. I would also tend to do early assignments to get rid of the nulls.

For testing, I also use a return value from function1, but other possible test methods may be created.

```
public EHandled function1(List<Integer> inList1, List<String> inList2)
{  
    // remove the need for null checks
    List<Integer> list1 = (inList1 != null ? inList1 : Collections.emptyList());
    List<String> list2 = (inList2 != null ? inList2 : Collections.emptyList());

    // if there are too many entries, then leave; this handles
    // cases of either list having > 1 element, or both lists having
    // >= 1 element
    if (! validNumberOfEntries(list1, list2)) {
        return EHandled.NONE;
    }

    if (list1.size() == 1) {
        return doSomethingWithIntList(list1);
    }
    else if (list2.size() == 1) {
        return doSomethingWithStringList(list2);
    }
    else {
        // should never happen; could also be handled by an assert
        System.err.println("Something wicked this way comes");
        return EHandled.ERROR;
    }
}


/**
 * If the total of the two lists is > 1, then there are too many entries;
 * if the total == 0, there are not enough
 * @param list1 A non-null list
 * @param list2 A non-null list
 */
public boolean validNumberOfEntries(List<Integer> list1, List<String> list2)
{
    int s1 = list1.size();
    int s2 = list2.size();
    return (s1 + s2 == 1);
}


public EHandled doSomethingWithIntList(List<Integer> list)
{
    System.out.println("Processing Integers");
    for (Integer i : list) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    return EHandled.INTEGERS;
}

public EHandled doSomethingWithStringList(List<String> list)
{
    System.out.println("Processing Strings");
    for (String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    return EHandled.STRINGS;
}

private enum EHandled
{
    NONE,
    INTEGERS,
    STRINGS,
    ERROR,
}
```

Sample Output:

> Processing Integers
>   1
>   Processing Strings
>   Hello World

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be simplified by dropping your if statement. For more readability and avoiding code duplication introduce a helper method:

```
public void function1(List<Integer> list1, List<String> list2) {
  if (isSingletonCollection(list1)) {
    doSomethingWithIntList(list1);
  } else if (isSingletonCollection(list2)) {
    doSomethingWithStringList(list2);
  }
}

private boolean isSingletonCollection(Collection<?> list) {
  return list != null && list.size() == 1;
}
```

Since you're using lists with different types there is no generic and typesafe way to solve your problem except using if-else statements.

Comment: Isn't this missing a condition where list1 and list2 each have a single entry? If so, it is not supposed to process. Or did I read it incorrectly?

Comment: I was looking at the code and it doesn't match the provided requirements. Since you've provided a solution to this I'll ommit that case.